# Laravel Eloquent belongsto relationship returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two Eloquent models:

1) Post

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'user_id', 'product_id', 'site_id', 'link_id', 'body', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
```

2) Product

```
protected $table = 'products';
protected $fillable = ['id', 'user_id', 'manufacturer_id', 'shift_product_id', 'name', 'english_name',
                        'slug', 'text', 'spec', 'live', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

I need to get the product from a post
I do that:

```
$posts = Post::get();

foreach($posts as $key){
    dd($key->product);
}
```

Like this it returns NULL
If I do like this:
 `dd($key->product());`
I get the product but I can't to use that
[image]

but I need to get something like that to use whant I need:

[image]

Comment: Is there a `post_id` column in your products table? If that isn&#39;t your foreign key to posts, pass the foreign key name as second argument to the `product` method in Post model

Comment: @linktoahref there is `product_id` on `posts` table, at least it looks like that based on `fillable` on `Post`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found my problem
i dont have in the DB product with ID = 1 
:/
stuped problem

thanks for all the help i leran alot from u.

Comment: please mark as correct and/or close this.

Comment: this was my stupid problem too thanks

Answer (score 16):

Try to point out foregin key and other key in relation, examples:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
}
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Should work. Try to change foregin_key with other_key. I am sure that the problem is in that point.

Comment: OP follows [Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions), so he doesn't need to define FK and PK in the relationship definition.

Comment: I don't know, sometimes I already followed the name convention of Laravel foreign key name, but it still returned `null` with `belongsTo` relationship.  Mentioning `foreign_key` after model name fixes that. Thanks man.

Comment: what do you mean by other_key ??

Comment: The key in the second table

Comment: the `null` means that in between your relationship one table has deleted_at.

Answer (score 3):

The relationship probably doesn't exist in the database.

Based on your `fillable` array on `Post`, the way you have the relationships setup looks correct as you are following naming conventions for keys and your `belongsTo` relationship methods have the correct name for convention.

`$post->product()` is not returning your `Product` model. It is returning a `Relation` type object (`BelongsTo`). This is used for querying the relationship. `$post->product` would be the dynamic property for the relationship that would return the already loaded relationship or load the relationship and give you the result.

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

If the relationships are setup correctly `$post->product` being `null` would mean the relationship doesn't actually exist in the database, no matching `id` in `products` for `product_id` or `product_id` being null. (assuming no foreign key constraint)

Side note: eager loading the relationship would be a good idea:

```
$posts = Post::with('product')->get();
```

Comment: i try that is still NULL, i upload my fiild in the DB so tell me if u think that i have a problem :/ tahnks

Comment: the relationship doesn't exist in the database

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this post because I got a similar error while working on a project.

What I discovered is that when you query a model with the all() method, it ignores the related softdeleted rows.

When you try to access them tho, you get the null

Answer (score 0):

Remember to hit save() after associate and dissociate. Got me a couple of times:

```
$model->relation()->associate($record)->save();
```