# Laravel eloquent relations always gives me null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:
Shippings

```
Schema::create('shippings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name',64);
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->enum('active', ['yes','no'])->default('yes');
    $table->enum('ZaPobraniem',['yes','no'])->default('no');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Orders

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->enum('status',['pending', 'paid','sent','done'])->default('pending');
    $table->string('email',64);
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->string('name',64);
    $table->string('secondname',64);
    $table->string('city',64);
    $table->string('street',64);
    $table->text('comment')->nullable();
    $table->string('phonenumber',9);
    $table->string('postalcode',10);
    $table->integer('shipping_id')->unsigned();

    $table->timestamps();
});

class Order extends Model
{
    const PENDING = 'pending';
    const PAID = 'paid';
    const SENT = 'sent';
    const DONE = 'done';

   
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class);
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function dostawy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Shipping::class);
    }
    
}
```

OrderProducts

```
Schema::create('order_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I'm trying to show details about specific order by running like this:

```
$order = Order::with('products','dostawy')->findOrFail($order_id);
```

but relation 'dostawy' is always null and I don't know why.
I tried changing relation to hasOne but it's even worse, can someone help me?

Comment: because in your `order` model you made the relation method with a different name so you need to add the `shipping_id`, `id` of your order like this`$this->belongsTo(Shipping::class, 'shipping_id', 'id')`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730514/laravel-eloquent-belongsto-relationship-returns-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `dostawy` as the relationship eloquent is going to be looking for a `dostawy_id` column on the orders table. You can easily override it by specifying what column you want the relationship to use like this:

```
$this->belongsTo(Shipping::class, 'shipping_id');
```

This will force the relationship to use the `shipping_id` column on the `orders` table and will automatically link it to the `id` column on the `shippings` table. Also, note that if you needed to override the name of the column on the shippings table you could pass it in as a third parameter.

As a side note, it may be beneficial to name the relation something like `shippingDetails` or something like that to make it more readable for any devs reading the codebase down the road (unless there is some business logic that lead to the current naming of course)!